# Show specific entries on a many-to-many relationship in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three tables: `illnesses`, `symptoms` and a third table to map the relationship between the first two, called `symptom_illness`. 
This third table has `symptom_id`, `illness_id` and its own `id`

I need a way to show, for example, all symptoms of a given "Common Cold" illness. In this example, "Common Cold" has an `id` of 1 and its symptoms have ids of 1 through 5. 
 
This means that `symptom_illness` has 5 entries, where:

```
symptom_illness.illness_id = 1, symptom_id = 1
symptom_illness.illness_id = 1, symptom_id = 2
symptom_illness.illness_id = 1, symptom_id = 3
```

And so on. I need a way to display, in a single page, all the symptoms that have the same `illness_id` but I can't seem to find a way how to.

EDIT 1: My classes are related as such:
Symptom:

```
has_many :symptom_illness
has_many :illnesses, through: :symptom_illness
```

And similar for Illness. 
Illness_symptom has `belongs_to :symptom` and `belongs_to :illness`

Comment: Can you post your models with associations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three models

```
class Symptom
  has_many :symptom_illnesses
  has_many :illnesses, through: :symptom_illnesses
end

class SymptomIllness
  belongs_to :illness
  belongs_to :symptom
end

class Illness
  has_many :symptom_illnesses
  has_many :symptoms, through: :symptom_illnesses
end
```

You can easily access al illness symptoms with something like that:

```
Illness.find(1).symptoms.each do |symptom|
  # do something with this symptom
end
```

What do you want to show in the page? 
If the symptom has a `name` attribute you can initialize a

```
@symptoms = Illness.find(1).symptoms
```

array in controlller and in the page you do something like

```
<% @symptomps.each do |symptom| %>
  <% = symptom.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This seems to work, but if added to my show.html.erb by itself it dumps the whole data for a given symptom. Where do you suggest I add the find.symptoms.each?

Comment: Turns out I had <%= instead of <%, thus it printed the whole array after running through it. This is exactly what I needed, though I changed Illness.find(1).symptoms to @illness.symptoms and fixed the code retroactively, to allow the page to always render the symptoms for its respective illness. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `has_many through:` relationship.

```
class Illness < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :symptom_illness
  has_many :symptom, through: :symptom_illness
end

class SymptomIllness < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :symptom
  belongs_to :illness
end

class Symptom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :symptom_illness
  has_many :illness, through: :symptom_illness
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: `has_and_belongs_to_many` has fallen out of favor with many rails developers.

Comment: Do you have a source and reasoning for that claim?

Comment: Rails style guide: "Prefer has_many :through to has_and_belongs_to_many. Using has_many :through allows additional attributes and validations on the join model."

Comment: The Rails 4 Way: "Before proceeding with this section, I must clear my conscience by stating that has_and_belongs_to_many is practically obsolete in the minds of many Rails developers, including the authors of this book. Use has_many :through instead and your life should be a lot easier."

Comment: Thanks for those references! When I know it's only ever going to be a join table, I still prefer habtm. I think in many cases you'll be defining a model that you're never going to use. The Rails core team doesn't seem to think it's obsolete, or they would've deprecated it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Symptom < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :symptom_illness
  has_many :ilnesses, through: symptom_illness
end

class SymptomIllness < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :symptom
  belongs_to :illness

  scope :ilness, ->(*i) {
    where(ilness_id: i.flatten.compact.uniq
  }
end

class Illness < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :symptom_illness
  has_many :symptoms, through: :symptom_illness

end

Ilness.find(1).symptoms
```

Comment: I realize that.. but the fact that his associative table has an id, it's advisable to make it a first class citizen

Comment: Please refer to the rails style guide, mainly the part that discusses the benefits of through as opposed to habtm relationship  https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide